# TextLabel isnt updating, Roblox, LUA

Tags: lua, roblox

I was expecting that the label will update every time the "value" changes, but it won't, the "value" is changing correctly. The TextLabel updates, but only when i reset character. Thanks for any help!

Also, I don't see any errors in Output.

```
local value = game.ServerScriptService.Round 
local text = game.StarterGui.Time.Frame.TextLabel


local function updateText()
    if value.Value == 1 then
        text.TextColor3 = Color3.new(0.952941, 0.807843, 0.0862745)
        text.Text = "BONUS ROUND!"
    elseif value.Value == 2 then
        text.TextColor3 = Color3.new(0.666667, 0, 0)
        text.Text = "Invasion!"
    elseif value.Value == 3 then
        text.TextColor3 = Color3.new(0.952941, 0.807843, 0.0862745) 
        text.Text = "Killer!"
    elseif value.Value == 4 then
        text.TextColor3 = Color3.new(0.333333, 0.666667, 1)
        text.Text = "Defence!"
    elseif value.Value == 5 then
        text.TextColor3 = Color3.new(0, 0.666667, 0)
        text.Text = "Towers Round!"
    end
end

value.Changed:Connect(updateText)

while true do
    value.Changed:Connect(updateText)
    updateText()
    wait() -- Add a small delay to avoid freezing the game
end
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can't store values in "ServerScriptService". In "ServerScriptService" you can only store scripts, localscripts and modulescripts, but you can store values in "ServerStorage" they are also stored on server, and you can't change them from client.
2. This script needs to be local and located in "StarterPlayer.StarterPlayerScripts" because you are changing player Gui which is individual for each player. Local scripts are running scripts for each player individual and other players can't see what local script is changed for some player except player character.
3. "StarterGui" is service from which game takes all objects such as Screen GUIs, Frames, Text Labels, etc. to every player Gui. If you are changing
   "TextLabel" in "StarterGui", you are changing "TextLabel" that game is going to take next time when another player joins the game. If you want to change Gui for every player, you can use: `game.Players.LocalPlayer` that gives you the player that local script is working on right now. Player Gui is located in `game.Players.PlayerName.PlayerGui` so, you can combine two things together and you get: `game.Players.LocalPlayer.PlayerGui`.

So, what you need is:

1. Change your value location to "ServerStorage"
2. Change: `local value = game.ServerScriptService.Round` to: `local value = game.ServerStorage.Round`
3. Change `local text = game.StarterGui.Time.Frame.TextLabel` to:

```
    local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
    local text = player.PlayerGui.Time.Frame.TextLabel
```

or to: `local text = game.Players.LocalPlayer.PlayerGui`

4. Change script to local script (if it's not local allready) and put this script at "StarterPlayer.StarterPlayerScripts".